Ubuntu OS doesn't install on my laptop and shows error: file ‘/boot/‘ not found is shown when i try to install ubuntu
my ubuntu crashed, don't know how and I tried to install ubuntu 24.04 LTS and it installed but after loging in, my data wasn't cleared and stayed there even after rebooting and tried to install it again and the ubuntu didn't installed after putting my information, it loaded and said 'System program problem detected' and had to press hard off button and again tried to install it again and it happened to have the same problem of not installing. After trying to install ubuntu again it showed "error: file ‘/boot/‘ not found" for a split second in the screen and showed try or install ubuntu etc

There is no actual info here that can be used to help you. How did you try to install it? How was the boot media made? What does my data was not cleared mean? This and other details are needed in order to offer any help.

"error: file ‘/boot/‘ not found" is not important it showed it also on my computer before installation. But if you want help please make it clear what do you want help with, edit your question and make it clear.

This report can show lots of info on your configuration. Also what brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Upgrade your system firmware.
